# How to get a border when an imageview has focus?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am making a game like chess in Android Studio with Java. I have many pawns. What I need is: when a user selects a pawn it will have a border. And when the user selects another pawn, this pawn will have a border **but the previous one will no longer have the border**.

Simply, has focus, has border. No focus, no border.

For this, I am using ImageView and setOnFocustChangeListener but in vain. The code I am trying:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_online_game);

    imgView1 = findViewById(R.id.e2);

    imgView1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                imgView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border);
            }
            else{
                imgView1.setBackground(null);
                Log.d("MSG", "NO FOCUS");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

This same code works for EditText.

But it is not working for an ImageView. Where is my mistake? how should I do it? Could anyone please help me...